# Supabase storage - Error Failed to load PDF document

Tags: next.js, supabase

I have a PDF which has been uploaded to Supabase storage. I can click `download` via the dashboard and can view my downloaded PDF locally or in chrome.

When I click `Get Url` or programmatically get the public URL, opening that in Chrome leads to an error with `Error Failed to load PDF document`. I'd like to be able to serve this PDF to my users in my Next.js app.

I have enabled an RLS policy on the bucket which allows everything for public, and the bucket itself is public.

Comment: Where exactly do you see the error message? Does adding an image to the same bucket and accessing it the same way work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to use `contentType: "application/pdf"` in the `FileOptions` when uploading. Not sure why it can infer the MIME type on console upload, but not programmatically.

```
const { data, error } = await supabase.storage.from('bucket').upload(uploadPath, pdfBytes, {upsert: true, contentType: "application/pdf"});
```